# Google Drive API files.get not returning latest file version

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a web page which uploads a local .docx file to a service account folder on Google Drive, embeds the uploaded document on the web page to edit, and then downloads the edited version of the file when the user clicks Save. However the files.get method used to download the edited file is consistently returning an out-of-date copy.

Code to upload the file:

```
<?php
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$fileMetadata->setName('Test Document.docx');
$fileMetadata->setParents(array(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID));

$content = file_get_contents($file_to_upload);

$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'data' => $content,
            'mimeType' => $original_mime_type,
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'fields' => '*'));
                            
$file_id = $file->id;
?>

<iframe id='google_drive_frame' src='https://docs.google.com/document/d/<?php echo $file_id; ?>/edit'></iframe>
```

I then add some text and wait for the 'Saved to Drive' status to appear - I have also checked the actual file on Google Drive displays all of the changes. Clicking save on my page then runs:

```
<?php
$response = $service->files->get($file_id, array('alt' => 'media'));

$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();

file_put_contents($local_file_path, $content);
?>
```

This is returning the file without any errors, but it is usually an out-of-date version of the file, either with none of the edited text or with a varying number of the changes in.

I have previously used almost exactly the same code but uploading as a Google Doc and then using files.export to download the edited file, and that worked absolutely fine. But this doesn't seem to work reliably using files.get. Am I doing something wrong or does this method not return real-time results?